# Deep ArView update frame output based on device orientation

Tags: ios

I am new in learning deepaR Sdk and integrated deepAR sdk (https://www.deepar.ai) in ios project which is working fine.
but issue is output frame  does not updated when device rotate to landscape or to protrait
i want to have a correct frame based on device orientation.

Landscape Video issue
[see video is shown in landscape mode inialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJCik.jpg)

Landscape Video expected
[This is expected result for landscape mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N63i9.jpg)

I have to do something in calling this startFrameOutput method but I don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem!

[image]

I did try use the method deepAR.setRenderingResolutionWithWidth like the documentation explain, after the orientationDidChange and apply the change in the cameraControl from the DeepAR:

```
self.deepAR.setRenderingResolutionWithWidth(Int(self.arViewContainer.frame.size.width ),
                                    height: Int(self.arViewContainer.frame.size.height) )
```

But I got this result:

[image]

So I did try multiply the value to two and was a successful result, but to understand why this functioned, I gone to the apple documentation and got this information

> var scale: CGFloat
> The natural scale factor associated with the screen.

From Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen

So I did update the code to consider the natural scale factor associated with the screen and the final code was looks like this

```
let screenScale = UIScreen.main.scale
   self.deepAR.setRenderingResolutionWithWidth(Int(self.arViewContainer.frame.size.width * screenScale) ,
                                                height: Int(self.arViewContainer.frame.size.height * screenScale) )
```

And I got this result:
[image]